# Firebase structure for ebay or craigslist like site

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire, nosql

I watched a lot of denormalization structures for firebase but can't figure out the right way for larger web apps like ebay or craigslist.

If you take the example of ebay or craigslist. How would you build up the structure for efficency with thousands/millions of items/categories?

Would this be the right way to proceed?

```
"users":{
    $userID: {
    ...
    }
},
"categories": {
    $categoryID (01): {
        "name": "computers"
        "subcategories": {
            $subCatID: {
            "name": "apple"
            }
        }
    },
    $categoryID (02): {
        "name": clothes
        ...
    }
},
"items": {
    $id: {
        "name": "iMac 27",
        "category": {
            $categoryID
            $subCatID
            ....
        },
        "seller": $userID,
        ...
    }  
}
```

What i don't understand is, if you want to get a specific item, would you need to download all the item from the "items" tree first? Does that lead to a performance problem with millions of items?

Many thanks for your help.
Stefan

Comment: Storing millions of items is a very efficient operation. Reading or querying millions of items is not. Everything depends on how you want to access the data. See this article for a good introduction on the patterns and considerations: https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/

Comment: If you know which item to get, it's a simple read: `ref.child('items').child(itemId')`.

Comment: Cross-post: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/qxF5d7eNFSE

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen
Thanks for your answer and the article. I'll read it.
I know how to get the item with `code`ref.child('items').child(itemId')`code` but what I'm asking is even if you target the right item, does it have to download all the parent tree first?

Comment: Not if you use the construct I show. Next time, show code and I'll be able to answer that immediately.

Answer (score 1):

If you know which item to get, you can get it with a simple read:

```
ref.child('items').child(itemId')
```

This directly accesses the child and does not require the database to consider all items, nor does it require the client to download all items. The database just directly loads the correct item from disk and returns only that item to the client.